# Extention OpenAPI (Swagger) Editor don`t work on Macbook Air M2

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, openapi

I installed Extention OpenAPI (Swagger) Editor on Macbook Air M2 and I don`t see this extention.
VS Version: 1.64.1 (Universal)

also I don't see anything on the tab OPENAPI
Restared VS and reinstall didn`t help
I can see an error

```
[2023-07-21 12:28:57.453] [renderer1] [error] Cannot read property 'installAndRestartMessage' of undefined: TypeError: Cannot read property 'installAndRestartMessage' of undefined
    at vscode-file://vscode-app/Applications/Visual%20Studio%20Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:1570:74473
[2023-07-21 12:31:12.312] [renderer1] [error] command 'openapi.createNewThreeYaml' not found: Error: command 'openapi.createNewThreeYaml' not found
    at b._tryExecuteCommand (vscode-file://vscode-app/Applications/Visual%20Studio%20Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:1489:3364)
    at vscode-file://vscode-app/Applications/Visual%20Studio%20Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:1489:3245
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at async i.open (vscode-file://vscode-app/Applications/Visual%20Studio%20Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:578:69304)
    at async a.open (vscode-file://vscode-app/Applications/Visual%20Studio%20Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:578:71090)
```